# What is a highly used syllabus (curriculum) or order of topics which can be used to self-study physics, and what are good books related to that?

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

I am an Indian High School student and I love to study physics, but studying it on your own has its own challenges, and I have never studied it systematically but today I realised that it would be much easier to do it that way so,

What is a highly recommended syllabus or curriculum which could be used to SELF- STUDY Physics from High school level (Olympiad preparation included) to University level?

What books could be read for those topics (High school level to University level)?

Note: This question is asked from the point of view of Self-Study, so please answer relevant to that.

Comment: I know of the MIT open undergraduate courses that can be use for self study. the order of subjects in the list is the order one would be taught in classes , the first in each subject the easiest, https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/

Comment: 't Hooft has put together a guide to becoming a theoretical physicist with resource recommendations https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~gadda001/goodtheorist/index.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Book recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations)

Comment: If you search the site for "books physics" you will find we have loads of questions and answers on this already.  You will also find answers to "free physics books".  Note that every B.Sc. course in the world has it's own reading lists and you will not find any one list.  Also everyone learns differently and responds to different books differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often textbook sources require a subscription for access. However, I recommend  https://openstax.org/subjects/view-all as they have many free textbooks available for High School/College level courses. You can read on-line or download a pdf of the entire book of interest without restriction.